# How to add a option to a questio(vote) onFacebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I succeed to post questoin on my wall.
But How can i add options to question?? i use the sources right below. ( addOption() )
and get a **"Neither a page id nor option text has been specified when adding an option to a question"**

What parameters are required? or
How can i get example of this? Not PHP or Javascript. in Android SDK.

public void addOption(String option)
    {

```
    if(facebook.isSessionValid())
    {
        AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Void> task = new AsyncTask<String,Boolean, Void>()
                {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
            {
                Boolean result = false;
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                String response = null;

                parameters.putString("options", params[0]);

                try
                {
                    response = facebook.request("318018398288233/options", parameters, "POST");

                    result = true;
                    Log.i(TAG, response);
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    result = false;
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                } 

                publishProgress(result);

                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... values)
            {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

                Boolean result = (Boolean) values[0];

                if(result == null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(BaseApplication.getContext(), "페이스북 담벼락 글쓰기 요청을 실패하였습니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(result)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(BaseApplication.getContext(), "페이스북 담벼락 글을 작성하였습니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //  String response = (String) values[1];
                    //  MessageUtil.alert(BaseApplication.getTopActivity(), response);
                }

            }

                };


                task.execute(option);
    }
    else
    {
        login();
    }
}
```